# Are there boycotts of university rankings?

Tags: ethics, bibliometrics, ranking, social-media

Motivation: Our university has asked us to provide contacts for possible referees for our university for the QS ranking; apparently this "find your own reviewers" system has a [40% weight](https://support.qs.com/hc/en-gb/articles/4405952675346-Academic-Reputation) in that ranking. I find the whole system flawed and open to gaming, and I am considering participating in some sort of boycott.

It is a widespread opinion that [academic](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/2980760) [rankings](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-college-rankings-considered-bad) [are](https://www.irishtimes.com/opinion/why-university-world-rankings-are-meaningless-1.3929601) [harm](https://www.forbes.com/sites/brennanbarnard/2018/09/28/end-college-rankings-an-open-letter-to-the-owners-and-editors-of-u-s-news-and-world-report/)[ful](https://www.universityworldnews.com/post.php?story=20170105122700949), so I was wondering if there is any ongoing boycott that I could participate to.

For instance, mathematicians have [boycotted Elsevier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cost_of_Knowledge) in the past, refusing to publish, review, and/or take editorial roles in journals from that publisher. If there is an organized movement like that for refusing to take part in academic rankings, I would be interested in a pointer.

Comment: It's not clear what kind of boycott would be possible: if you (a university) don't play the game, I suspect that the rankings will come out anyway, simply with your university at a lower ranking. You won't care, but others will.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano A large enough boycott would undermine the credibility of those rankings; I consider this as a desirable outcome.

Comment: I resent it's disdain for the humanities subjects and dislike it's favoritism for stem fields. According to it the school that teaches a person how to fix a Xerox machine is a much better gauge of academic success than the school that train the people who teach your daughter how to draw.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni most of the criteria they judge unis by is knowledge open to the public.

Comment: I was at a university that gamed the median class size statistic by making several sections of 19 students each, and dumping the rest in an enormous class. I protested because on average this results in more students having a worse experience, but they claimed it was good because they would put the "best" instructor on the big section.

Comment: @NickMatteo that sounds like a pretty effective way to undermine the credibility of the the ranking system. If the students complain you can tell them it's a performance piece on the perils of naive evaluations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There have been boycotts at university level, but not boycotts of the kind you're thinking of.

Example as happened at [Syracuse University](https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2014/01/06/syracuse-after-refusing-play-rankings-game-may-care-again), which led to a rankings slide before they decided to care again.

**Edit**: here's another [example](https://indianexpress.com/article/india/seven-iits-continue-boycott-no-indian-institute-in-top-300-7487854/) of a boycott at university level by several Indian Institutes of Technology.

Comment: Universities that are boycotting US News ranking can sometimes be found at the bottom of the rankings with a note saying there is missing data.

Comment: [Oxford](https://www.oxfordsu.org/news/article/6013/Boycott-the-NSS/), [Cambridge](https://www.cambridgesu.co.uk/yourvoice/projects/nssboycott/), [KCL](https://www.kclsu.org/change/campaigns/past/boycottnss/), and a few more student unions successfully boycott NSS rankings since 2017.